# GORM Map with Collection as values

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a GRAILS domain object with the property:

```
Map<String, Collection<String>> reportIds
```

When I try to save the object I get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.StringTypeDescriptor.unwrap(StringTypeDescriptor.java:40)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:52)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:91)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:283)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:278)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.java:89)
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.writeElement(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:815)
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1203)
at org.hibernate.action.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:58)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:188)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.events.PatchedDefaultFlushEventListener.performExecutions(PatchedDefaultFlushEventListener.java:46)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:656)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:147)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:189)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withTransaction(GormStaticApi.groovy:573)
```

I tried defining the property as:

```
Map<String, String[]> ...
```

as well but no luck.

It looks like Hibernate is expecting it to be a Map<String, String> and isn't handling things correctly.

Anyone have any idea how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 4):

Simple maps must have string keys & values, see: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#sets,ListsAndMaps.  I think your best bet is to create a separate domain class to serve as the value for your Map entries.

Comment: The doc says "In this case the key and value of the map MUST be strings". Does this apply to mongodb as well?